# pulling and pushing data from and into vbulletin system

Tags: php, mysql, ios, sdk, vbulletin

I'm building an application for vBulletin Forum, And I need to be able to **create posts**, **get posts**, **send private messages** and **login (With external Library, [Gigya](http://www.gigya.com))**. I searched the internet, and found [vBulletin's API](https://members.vbulletin.com/api/). And found some `PHP` functions that will help me fetch and post posts - but if there is a function for posting - where is the login?! how the system will know who is posting?!

So, How I can use this system?!
If somebody tried ever to build something with vBulletin - Please help me.

Comment: I see a `build_new_post` function in the API documentation which "Creates a new post"

Comment: yeah, but see.. `build_new_post ([string $type = 'thread'], array $foruminfo, array $threadinfo, array $postinfo, array &$post, array &$errors)` where I place the user here? and how I login the user on the mobile (not through the vBulletin Forum)

Comment: [It seems to be](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-legacy-versions-products/legacy-vbulletin-versions/vbulletin-3-5-how-do-i-questions-and-troubleshooting/161489-build-new-post) set in the `$post` array argument, although I am not sure of the formatting of that array.

Comment: It's not very well documented, so good luck! Post your answer here when you find one

Comment: I'm coming slowly to the conclusion that if you want to interact with vBulletin, it's best to just do normal web scraping; nobody seems to have succeeded with the web API.